# TabBar disappear when segue even NavigationController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Well, I'm faced with misunderstanding.
I want my `UITabBar` to stay displayed when I make a segue from my History button (see picture).

- My segue is on Show.
- My view is embed in a `UINavigationController` that is root controller at my `UITabBarController`.
- "Show navigation bar" is turned off on my `UINavigationController`.

And with all that, I have a grey screen on my segue and no `UITabBar`...

Thank you in advance!

[image: Part of my structure of storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a popup view.
In the storyboard remember to set the identifier for the view controller that you are going to. Then delete the segue.

```
 let customAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view") as! yourViewController
    self.addChild(customAlert)
    self.view.addSubview(customAlert.view)
    customAlert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Hi,
It's an effect a solution that can work (to manage it in the code and not from the storyboard) But it prevents me from having the default features of my push (like the back Button on the top bar for example). It's a shame to do it all over again manually, do you think it's really the only solution :/ ? Thx

Comment: I do think that may be the only option because that view controller isn’t connected to the tab bar. The other view is.

Comment: But also looking at your design I don’t think it’s necessary to be able to access the tab bar. But that’s just my opinion.

Comment: well, thank you, I'll settle for your solution then:)

Comment: Great. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make Segue kind as "Show". When select as "Show Detail", the ViewController is present over the Tabbar and hides it.

[image]

Comment: Can you delete the segue add it again with kind Show?

Comment: Yeah same effect .. !